# "Some of your past questions have not been well-received". How to count the endpoint?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I got a warning notification "Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more." and I'm afraid to ask my next question, because I don't know if somebody downvote, no one will answer or flag question. How can it counts, I mean where is the border of "well-received questions"? It is total score of my questions or how system count when is enough to be blocked? 
P.S. So sorry, if it is a little stupid question, but this is my first question on Meta and really want to understand it better.
Thanks.

Comment: The formula is secret on purpose so that users won't go and bypass it.

Comment: It's great that you want to improve your question asking skills; too many people don't even bother. I suggest that you go to the Meta for the site where you've received this warning and ask. Something along the lines of "some of my recent questions haven't done so well; how can I improve them". I think that most people there will be happy to help you.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce, thanks. In some cases I really didn't understand why people downvoted or just passed through my questions, although I formatted it well, tried to give more general title, always provided stacktraces and useful additional details. But then I just found that my question are you too narrow to particular API or just too casual, so people don't pay to much attention on it. This is what I figured out. Thank you for the comment though :)